# Google Cardboard SDK for UNITY - detect device compatibility

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am adding cardboard support to the existing game and want to give the player option to play in cardboard mode.
I found that many devices do not support Google Cardboard SDK and want to check the compatibility in the app in order to show the button for choosing the cardboard mode only if device is compatible.
After googling for week, I did not found any working solution for this issue.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for each component for example you can check if device supports, [gyroscope](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-supportsGyroscope.html), [accelerometer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-supportsAccelerometer.html) and maybe some other components required to use GoogleCardboard. This will eliminate some of devices.

Comment: Don't forget screen size, there are no tablet sized cardboards. [Google says it supports up to 6 inches](https://vr.google.com/cardboard/get-cardboard/).

Comment: Yes, SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope is detecting correctly according to tests I made with my devices. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerator PutInCardBoard () {

    Debug.Log ("Put support on Display");

    if (SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope) {
        EnableAndDisableGyro [0].SetActive (true);
    } else {
        EnableAndDisableGyro [1].SetActive (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Tony , I use that to delect device support cardbord or not.

Comment: Yes, SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope is detecting correctly according to tests I made with my devices. Thanks.